# Add a cell value for duplicate rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script that deletes duplicate rows in a Google Sheet:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[1] == newData[j][1]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Now I want to modify it to NOT delete the duplicate rows but instead adding "DUPLICATE: " at the beginning of the detected duplicates in both rows/cells (the script is scanning only column 2 (B)) and color them orange but I cannot find out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need a double loop, but it's not necessary to have `newData` array; the `data` array can be modified in place. If two rows match in column B, both get "Duplicate" in Column A. Explicit bounds in for loops make it easy to avoid comparing a row with itself.

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (data[i][1] == data[j][1]) {
      data[i][0] = "Duplicate";
      data[j][0] = "Duplicate";
    }
}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

---

By the way, this logic could be implemented without a script, using Google Sheets formulas such as

```
=if(countif(B:B, B2) > 1, "Duplicate", )
```

(This is placed in A2, and copied down the column)

Or, as an array formula in A2:

```
=arrayformula(if(countif(B:B2, B:B2) > 1, "Duplicate", ))
```

Comment: Is there a method to use the formula as an ArrayFormula? Currently simply by adding that in front it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, I added that. The second argument should be array to be looked up in the first argument.